# Documents not searchable in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, sharepoint-search

I created a test document and it is not appearing in my SharePoint Search Results

1. I already enabled Search and Offline Availability -
   Allow this site to appear in search results? (YES)
2. I already enabled Advanced Settings - Allow items from this document library to appear in search results? - (YES)
3. I already enabled Advanced Settings - Allow non-default views from this list to appear in search results? - (YES)
4. I Re-indexed the Document Library too.

I dont know what else to do.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do this:

1.Verify draft items are crawled.
This behavior can be altered in Document Library Settings > Versioning Settings > Draft Item Security.

Select the option Any user who can read items.

This will allow all users to see draft items including the crawling account.

2.Verify the site's search visibility options at the following location:

<site_name>/_layouts/srchvis.aspx

Make sure that the Allow this site to appear in Search results option is selected.

**Parent site and sub site-specific search issues**:

The default setting for search visibility is one of the following options:

- **Do not index Web Parts if this site contains fine-grained permissions**
- **Always index all Web Parts on this site**
- **Never index any Web Parts on this site**

If a subsite on the site collection doesn't inherit permissions, .aspx pages won't appear in the search results. To resolve this issue, set the search visibility option in Srchvis.aspx to Always index all Web Parts on this site. Additionally, you may set the subsite to inherit permissions from the parent site.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already did the 2 settings you mentioned above and still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to check-in the item.

If you set up a library in a way that it requires check-in and check-out of documents, then a newly uploaded document is not checked in and before the first check-in it is not searchable. MS support told me that was the intended behavior, not a bug, so I hope they will in future add the feature that such items are searchable, or that the user can define, that new items are automatically checked-in?